# How can I capitalize all letters in an NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uppercase

I'm trying to capitalize all letters in a `NSString` for a table cell label.

Here's my code:

```
  // cell title and subtitle
cell.nameLabel.text = listingNode.title;
[cell.nameLabel.text uppercaseString];
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

Comment: Try cell.nameLabel.text = [listingNode.title uppercaseString];

Comment: @AnkitJain normally before posting a comment/solution, one would look at the several answers that were already posted to see if that same solution had been provided. In this case, 5 identical answers were posted several minutes earlier.

Comment: @mah I didn't realize that it had been answered already. My mistake.

Comment: @AnkitJain it's ok, answer overlaps happen frequently, just not usually with so much time between them on simple answers ;)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The method `uppercaseString` returns an uppercased representation of the receiver. Which means you need to collect the returned string and apply that to the label as text.

Try this,

```
NSString *uppercase = [cell.nameLabel.text uppercaseString];
cell.nameLabel.text =  uppercase;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString * str=@"jit";

NSLog(@"%@",[str uppercaseString]);


cell.nameLabel.text=[str uppercaseString];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to just convert your string to uppercase

```
cell.nameLabel.text=[String_name uppercaseString];
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about that.

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [listingNode.title uppercaseString];
```

Answer (score 0):

uppercaseString returns a value - NSString that contains the result of the operation.

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [listingNode.title uppercaseString];
```